# How to encode more than 3 characters in an 8*8 DataMatrix?

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, encoding

I am working on a Datamatrix Encoding Project. We are following ISO200 standard for Datamatrix Encoding, but with an 8*8 Datamatrix we are able to encode only 3 alphabetic or 6 numeric values. Is there any way to encode more data in an 8*8 Datamatrix?

Comment: No matter the algorithm, it will most likely be very different depending on the language selected. So please pick one preferred language.

Comment: I am using ASII datamode to encode barcode data.

Answer (score 1):

Google suggests you mean ECC200, and then searching on that shows more hits. As I expected, that standard includes extra bits of "redundant" information to allow "reconstruction of the entire encoded data string when the symbol has sustained 30% damage, assuming the matrix can still be accurately located. Data Matrix has an error rate of less than 1 in 10 million characters scanned." (quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix#Data_Matrix_ECC_200))

If you reduce the amount of error catching you can store up to 8 of 256 ANSI chars, 9 of 128 ASCII chars or >16 digits, and better if you allow for compression, but with no redundencies to allow for error correction.

Nevertheless, you probably just want to find another standard that puts more data and less error correction into the Datamatrix.